# Right way to Redirect a URL segment to MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have an existing Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Redirect("/Scorecard");

    }

    [OutputCache(Duration = 18000)]
    public ActionResult Scorecard()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This currently Maps to http://siteurl/Home/Scorecard . I wanted to the segment http://siteurl/scorecard to redirect to this Controller Action . What would the best wayt to do this . I tried checking the RequestUrl in Session_Start in Global.aspx but the redirects dont seem to be happening . The other alternative I thought of was using a Different Controller like "ScorecardController" and then having a RedirectToAction("Scorecard","Home") in the Index view there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add a FilterAccess class on your App_Start folder to do something like this:

```
public class FilterAcess : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
   {
       //Redirect
       if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url=="http://siteurl/scorecard"){
             context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Home/Scorecard");
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`RedirectToAction` is better way to do it, because, in case you change routing table later, redirect URL will be in adapted.

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Scorecard");
    }

    [OutputCache(Duration = 18000)]
    public ActionResult Scorecard()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

You should also update `RouteTable` with additional route, before "Default" route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "NoHomeSegmentInUrl",
        url: "{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

And, for lower case routes you need line `routes.LowercaseUrls = true;`